# What are the advantages of Packet Inspection and SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST over PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA?

Tags: mysql

We have several MySQL Servers (v 5.1) scattered across different geo locations. We are considering upgrading to the latest MySQL version as we heard a lot of good things about `PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA` available in MySQL v5.6.14 and above.

Can we not keep the current version and monitor it using the features like `Packet inspection`, `Show Full Processlist` and avoid the time consuming task of upgrading all the servers? Aren’t these features as good as the services of `PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA` to monitor the queries?

Answer (score 0):

With Performance schema database, MySQL introduced many tables which contain a lot of useful information like; the queries executed, example query, replication slave status etc. The other methods which you mentioned are quite useful but have their own drawbacks. Show full processlist is a good method but it may not capture all the queries running on your MySQL server depending on how frequently “show full processlist” query is executed, for e.g: if show full process list is being executed after every one second, still queries running for less than a second will not be captured. Performance schema, on the other hand, maintains a table which logs each and every query running on your MySQL server in one of its table, also it provides extra information for each of the queries executed like rows sent/examined, Disk/Memory temporary tables etc. I am not sure about the packet inspection method, so cannot comment on it.